# Histogram of uniform distribution not plotted correctly in R

Tags: r

When I run the code

```
hist(1:5)
```

or

```
hist(c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

The generated histogram shows that the first number "1" has frequency of 2 when there is only one "1" in the array.

[image]

I also tried

```
hist(c(1,2,3,7,7,7,9))
```

but it still shows that the first bar is twice times higher than the second one

[image]

However when I run

```
 hist(c(1:10))
```

The frequency height of every bars are equal

I'm pretty new to statistics and R so I don't know what is the reason behind this. I hope somebody can help me clarify why is this happening. Thank you

[image]

Comment: For the records, whenever you're dealing with a discrete variable that doesn't assumes so many values, it may be more interesting to plot your data like so: `plot(table(1:5))`. That way, you don't lose information about the specific values, unlike what happens when you plot a histogram.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taking your first example, `hist(1:5)`, you have five numbers, which get put into four bins. So two of those five get lumped into one.

The histogram has breaks at `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5`, so you can reasonably infer that the definition of `hist` for where a number is plotted, is:

```
#pseudocode
if (i <= break) { # plot in bin }
```

You can specify the breaks manually to solve this:

```
hist(1:5, breaks=0:5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
> trace("hist.default", quote(print(fuzzybreaks)), at = 25)
Tracing function "hist.default" in package "graphics"
[1] "hist.default"
>
> out <- hist(1:5)
Tracing hist.default(1:5) step 25 
[1] 0.9999999 2.0000001 3.0000001 4.0000001 5.0000001
> out$count
[1] 2 1 1 1
```

which shows the actual `fuzzybreaks` value it is using as well as the count in each bin.  Clearly there are two points in the first bin (between `0.9999999` and `2.0000001`) and one point in every other bin.

Compare with:

```
> out <- hist(1:5, breaks = 0:5 + 0.5)
Tracing hist.default(1:5, breaks = 0:5 + 0.5) step 25 
[1] 0.4999999 1.5000001 2.5000001 3.5000001 4.5000001 5.5000001
> out$count
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

Now there is clearly one point in each bin.

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing is that hist is placing `1:5` into four bins. So there will be one bin with 2 counts.

If you specify the cutoff points like so:

```
 hist(1:5, breaks=(c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5 , 5.5)))
```

then you will get the behaviour that you expect.