# Random bar in histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I have a bunch of dates that correspond to customer calls.  So if I count the number of times each date is listed I can see the frequency of calls.  I have attempted to do this with a histogram and I'm getting some unexpected behavior.  I get a very large bar (appears to be as big as the largest) on the first day of the year, but a `table()` of the data doesn't show that as accurate.  Any explanation would be appreciated.  I added an image of the histogram plus code and subset below.

[hist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRBUn.png)

```
hist(call2015$Date, freq=TRUE, breaks="days", axes=F)
Axis(side=2)
axis.Date(side=1, at=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), by="months"))

df15 <- as.data.frame(table(call2015$Date))
df15 <- df15[order(df15$Freq, decreasing=TRUE), ]
> head(df15)
      Var1 Freq
165 2015-06-14  132
346 2015-12-12  103
129 2015-05-09  101
290 2015-10-17   99
210 2015-07-29   97
157 2015-06-06   96
```

`> head <- head(call2015$Date,4000)`

> dput(head)
>   structure(c(16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
>   16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
>   16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
>   16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
>   16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
>   16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
>   16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
>   16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 16436, 
>   16436, 16436, 16436, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 
>   16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 
>   16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 
>   16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 
>   16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 
>   16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 
>   16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16437, 16438, 16438, 16438, 
>   16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 
>   16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 
>   16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 
>   16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 
>   16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 16438, 
>   16438, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 
>   16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 
>   16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 
>   16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 
>   16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 
>   16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 
>   16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 
>   16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 
>   16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 
>   16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 
>   16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 
>   16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 
>   16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16440, 16441, 16441, 16441, 
>   16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 
>   16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 
>   16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 
>   16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 
>   16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 16441, 
>   16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 
>   16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 
>   16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 
>   16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 
>   16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 16442, 
>   16442, 16442, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 
>   16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 
>   16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 
>   16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 
>   16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 
>   16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 
>   16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 
>   16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16443, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
>   16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
>   16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
>   16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
>   16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
>   16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 
>   16444, 16444, 16444, 16444, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 
>   16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 
>   16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 
>   16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 
>   16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 
>   16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 
>   16445, 16445, 16445, 16445, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 
>   16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 
>   16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 
>   16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 
>   16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 
>   16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 
>   16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 
>   16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16446, 16447, 
>   16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 
>   16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447, 16447,

Comment: Some potential duplicates, I think, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22424233/324364), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28006210/324364) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23741371/324364). The binning for histograms can get complicated...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @joran.  It looks like I should use `plot()` instead of `hist()`.  The only problem I'm having now is that my code for the x axis isn't working.  I was using `axis.Date(side=1, at=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), by="months"))` and i guess it doesn't work in `plot()`.  I know I can manually create the axis with the month names as characters, but do you know if `plot()` has similar date functionality?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without a more complete data set, but it looks like the largest counts are for January 1 and maybe June 15? Both of these are good candidates for "filler" values when the date is actually unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jdobres. It looks like I should use plot() instead of hist(). The only problem I'm having now is that my code for the x axis isn't working. I was using axis.Date(side=1, at=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), by="months")) and i guess it doesn't work in plot(). I know I can manually create the axis with the month names as characters, but do you know if plot() has similar date functionality? Thanks again.